# Multiple joins and last N rows per each parent

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables.

```
companies
- id
- name
- user_id

departments
- id
- name
- user_id
- company_id

invoices
- id
- department_id
- price
- created_at
```

I am trying to get all the data I will need for a "dashboard" screen in 1 big mysql query for performance purposes.  It's important to mention that invoices table has like 700k records and will only keep increasing in size.

So I need to get all user's companies, departments, and last 2 invoices for each department (2 highest dates of each id).

Now I don't have problems with first 2, which I could do easily such as:

```
SELECT companies.id as company_id, companies.name as company_name, departments.id as department_id, departments.name as department_name
FROM companies
LEFT JOIN departments
ON companies.id = departments.company_id
WHERE companies.user_id = 1
```

I'm just struggling with getting latest 2 invoices of each department.  What would be the best way to do that within that same query?

Here's data as requested, and [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a956/1) of same.

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(6,2)  NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `companies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `departments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `invoices`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `companies`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `departments`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `invoices`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO companies
  (`name`, `user_id`)
VALUES
  ('Google', 1),
  ('Apple', 1),
  ('IBM', 1)
;

INSERT INTO departments
  (`name`, `user_id`, `company_id`)
VALUES
  ('Billing', 1, 1),
  ('Support', 1, 1),
  ('Tech', 1, 1),
  ('Billing Dept', 1, 2),
  ('Support Dept', 1, 2),
  ('Tech Dept', 1, 2),
  ('HR', 1, 3),
  ('IT', 1, 3),
  ('Executive', 1, 3)
;

INSERT INTO invoices
  (`price`, `created_at`, `department_id`)
VALUES
  (155.23, '2016-04-07 14:39:29', 1),
  (123.23, '2016-04-07 14:40:26', 1),
  (150.50, '2016-04-07 14:40:30', 1),
  (123.23, '2016-04-07 14:41:38', 1),
  (432.65, '2016-04-07 14:44:15', 1),
  (323.23, '2016-04-07 14:44:22', 2),
  (541.43, '2016-04-07 14:44:33', 2),
  (1232.23, '2016-04-07 14:44:36', 2),
  (433.42, '2016-04-07 14:44:37', 2),
  (1232.43, '2016-04-07 14:44:39', 2),
  (850.40, '2016-04-07 14:44:46', 3),
  (133.32, '2016-04-07 14:45:11', 3),
  (12.43, '2016-04-07 14:45:15', 3),
  (154.23, '2016-04-07 14:45:25', 3),
  (132.43, '2016-04-07 14:46:01', 3),
  (859.55, '2016-04-07 14:53:11', 4),
  (123.43, '2016-04-07 14:53:45', 4),
  (433.33, '2016-04-07 14:54:14', 4),
  (545.12, '2016-04-07 14:54:54', 4),
  (949.99, '2016-04-07 14:55:10', 4),
  (1112.32, '2016-04-07 14:53:40', 5),
  (132.32, '2016-04-07 14:53:44', 5),
  (42.43, '2016-04-07 14:53:48', 5),
  (545.34, '2016-04-07 14:53:56', 5),
  (2343.32, '2016-04-07 14:54:05', 5),
  (3432.43, '2016-04-07 14:54:02', 6),
  (231.32, '2016-04-07 14:54:22', 6),
  (1242.33, '2016-04-07 14:54:54', 6),
  (232.32, '2016-04-07 14:55:12', 6),
  (43.12, '2016-04-07 14:55:23', 6),
  (4343.23, '2016-04-07 14:55:24', 7),
  (1123.32, '2016-04-07 14:55:31', 7),
  (4343.32, '2016-04-07 14:55:56', 7),
  (354.23, '2016-04-07 14:56:04', 7),
  (867.76, '2016-04-07 14:56:12', 7),
  (45.76, '2016-04-07 14:55:54', 8),
  (756.65, '2016-04-07 14:56:08', 8),
  (153.74, '2016-04-07 14:56:14', 8),
  (534.86, '2016-04-07 14:56:23', 8),
  (867.65, '2016-04-07 14:56:55', 8),
  (433.56, '2016-04-07 14:56:32', 9),
  (1423.43, '2016-04-07 14:56:54', 9),
  (342.56, '2016-04-07 14:57:11', 9),
  (343.75, '2016-04-07 14:57:23', 9),
  (1232.43, '2016-04-07 14:57:34', 9)
;
```

Here's the desired result.

```
company_id| company_name| department_id | department_name | invoice_price | invoice_created_at
         1| Google      |             1 | Billing         |        123.23 | 2016-04-07 14:41:38 | 
         1| Google      |             1 | Billing         |        432.65 | 2016-04-07 14:44:15 | 
         1| Google      |             2 | Support         |        433.42 | 2016-04-07 14:44:37 | 
         1| Google      |             2 | Support         |       1232.43 | 2016-04-07 14:44:39 | 
         1| Google      |             3 | Tech            |        154.23 | 2016-04-07 14:45:25 | 
         1| Google      |             3 | Tech            |        132.43 | 2016-04-07 14:46:01 | 
         2| Apple       |             4 | Billing Dept    |        545.12 | 2016-04-07 14:54:54 | 
         2| Apple       |             4 | Billing Dept    |        949.99 | 2016-04-07 14:55:10 | 
         2| Apple       |             5 | Support Dept    |        545.34 | 2016-04-07 14:53:56 | 
         2| Apple       |             5 | Support Dept    |       2343.32 | 2016-04-07 14:54:05 | 
         2| Apple       |             6 | Tech Dept       |        232.32 | 2016-04-07 14:55:12 | 
         2| Apple       |             6 | Tech Dept       |         43.12 | 2016-04-07 14:55:23 | 
         3| IBM         |             7 | HR              |        354.23 | 2016-04-07 14:56:04 | 
         3| IBM         |             7 | HR              |        867.76 | 2016-04-07 14:56:12 | 
         3| IBM         |             8 | IT              |        534.86 | 2016-04-07 14:56:23 | 
         3| IBM         |             8 | IT              |        867.65 | 2016-04-07 14:56:55 | 
         3| IBM         |             9 | Executive       |        343.75 | 2016-04-07 14:57:23 | 
         3| IBM         |             9 | Executive       |       1232.43 | 2016-04-07 14:57:34 |
```

Comment: "Now I don't have problems with first 2 ..." - Your query is not doing that.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks.  I added SQL fiddle data.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Not sure why you think that. See the SQL fiddle link I posted which shows that query performing as desired.

Comment: @zen "I don't have problems with first 2" - sorry, I thought you mean first two invoices. But now I guess you mean first two tables.

Comment: @Strawberry I added the desired result comma-delimited. Hope that helps to clarify the issue.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yep I meant the first two tables, sorry.  The answer submitted by Tommy May below does achieve what you initially thought I meant.

Comment: Does it need to be a `LEFT JOIN`? Are there companies without departments? Are there departments withoit invoices? And do you need to show them all?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, technically there are companies without departments when you just create a new company and have not yet created any departments under that company.  Same thing for invoices. When the department is first created, it will have no invoices until they are automatically generated. I think your answer will definitely work as it's super fast on a large set of data which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to include one more JOIN with the `invoices` table

```
LEFT JOIN invoices i ON  i.department_id = departments.id
```

This way you get all invoices for every department. But you need to limit them to the last two per department. One way would be an additional IN condition with a correlated subquery using LIMIT 2

```
LEFT JOIN invoices i
  ON  i.department_id = departments.id
  AND i.id IN (
    SELECT i1.id
    FROM invoices i1
    WHERE i1.department_id = departments.id
    ORDER BY i1.id DESC
    LIMIT 2
  )
```

But for some strange reasons MySQL doesn't allow to use `LIMIT` in an `IN` statement. So we need to be more tricky and avoid the IN condition. Instead we can use `>=` and select the second highest id using `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`:

```
  AND i.id >= (
    SELECT i1.id
    FROM invoices i1
    WHERE i1.department_id = departments.id
    ORDER BY i1.id DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 1
  )
```

Now the last problem: If there is only one invoice, we will not find the second one. The subquery would retun NULL and the condition will always fail. In that case we replace NULL with `0` using `COALESCE`.

So the final query would look like:

```
SELECT companies.id as company_id,
       companies.name as company_name,
       departments.id as department_id,
       departments.name as department_name,
       i.id as invoice_id,
       i.price as invoice_price
FROM companies
LEFT JOIN departments
  ON companies.id = departments.company_id
LEFT JOIN invoices i
  ON  i.department_id = departments.id
  AND i.id >= COALESCE((
    SELECT i1.id
    FROM invoices i1
    WHERE i1.department_id = departments.id
    ORDER BY i1.id DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 1
  ), 0)
WHERE companies.user_id = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a956/14

Comment: This works great in SQL fiddle but it's bombing out on my live data.  The invoices table has 700k rows, the departments has 1.5k, and companies 25, so that's probably why.  Any idea how efficient this is on a large dataset and what indexes would possible help?  Right now I just have primary key indexes for id columns.

Comment: @zen You should at least have indexes on every foreign key. Most important `invoices.department_id`.

Comment: Duh that makes sense. I added the indexes for foreign keys and it executed in 0.0098 seconds! It is incredibly fast. Thank you so much I can definitely use this going forward.

Comment: I wanted to ask you one more question.  What part in that query is limiting to 2 latest invoices?

Comment: @zen The join condition `AND i.id >= (...)`. The subquery selects the second highest ID for the given department using `ORDER BY i1.ID DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`. Thus you would only get rows with ID greater or equal to the second greatest ID. If you need a limit of 10 you would use `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9` - that means "skip 9 and take 1" wich is the 10th row.

Comment: Got it. Makes sense now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit, I'm struggling a little with how your result set matches up with your description and the data set, but here's something to play with...

```
SELECT x.price
     , x.created_at
     , x.department_id
     , x.department
     , x.department_user 
     , x.company_id
     , x.company
     , x.company_user 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT i.id
            , i.price
            , i.created_at
            , i.department_id
            , d.name department
            , d.user_id department_user 
            , d.company_id
            , c.name company
            , c.user_id company_user
            , CASE WHEN @prev=department_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev := i.department_id
         FROM invoices i 
         JOIN departments d 
           ON d.id = i.department_id 
         JOIN companies c 
           ON c.id = d.company_id
         JOIN (SELECT @prev:=null, @i:=0) vars
        ORDER 
           BY department_id
            , created_at DESC
     ) x
 WHERE i<=2;
```

Here's a slower way of conceptualising the same idea (I've left out the less relevant bits)...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM invoices x 
  JOIN invoices y 
    ON y.department_id = x.department_id 
   AND y.created_at <= x.created_at 
 GROUP 
    BY x.department_id
     , x.created_at
HAVING COUNT(*) <=2;
```

Comment: Yea it kinda works however on my live data it is taking about 7-8 seconds.  I think Paul Spiegel's answer is much faster and more accurate as far as desired result goes.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @zen I seriously doubt that. But hey, whatever works, right? ;-)

Comment: @zen ... and the index should be on (department_id, created_at)

Comment: that index sped it up by about 1 second.  Fastest I got it was 6.6620 seconds.  Plus as you mentioned, it is also not returning the correct result completely even in the test case.

Comment: @zen To be fair, I didn't use `createt_at` in my query assuming that `ID` is in the same order. What is the runtime if you use `ORDER BY department_id, i.ID DESC`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I changed it to that, but it's still returning similar times `~6.8891 seconds`. It doesn't seem like changing it between `created_at` and `id` in this case helps it either way.